# OpenStack IP address not found

Tags: virtualbox, openstack, devstack

I'm trying to deploy OpenStack via DevStack on a Ubuntu Server LTS distribution with Virtual Box.

After follow all this [steps](https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/) I am unable to access to Horizon on a web browser on my Host Machine Distribution (Windows10). I have checked with ifconfig all IPs and any of them took me to the Horizon Portal.

I have also checked /etc/network/interfaces and /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf, and the first one is almost empty and the second one doesn't exists.

I know I have connection cause I successfully ping google and linux.com on the terminal, but seems I am not using the right IP at the time I tried to enter Horizon.

What can I do? What am I doing wrong?

IPs (ifconfig):
[image: IPs (ifconfig)]

Comment: did you put `HOST_IP` in the `local.conf` when you were deploying the devstack?

Comment: No, i added it on stackrc file

Comment: I update this with the solution I've found. The error was the ports were closed (I thought all was open), so I followed this guide: https://www.howtogeek.com/122641/how-to-forward-ports-to-a-virtual-machine-and-use-it-as-a-server/ and opened the TCP conection on port 80. The IP address was the localhost (127.0.0.1) but with the port closed it never conect. Now it works perfectly.